# Maven raises java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to install and use Maven on a Mac OS X 10.8.5,

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

and

```
$env
PATH=/Users/dev/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/dev/.rbenv/shims:/Users/dev/.rbenv/shims:/Users/dev/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/dev/.rvm/bin:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin
TMPDIR=/var/folders/ds/y8xcz0v92c31y9618cvfd6s80000gn/T/
SHELL=/bin/zsh
HOME=/Users/dev
USER=dev
LOGNAME=dev
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-w886dP/Listeners
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-kJun90/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-NRuj9p/Render
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-PBxe8n/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:7
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=309
TERM_SESSION_ID=0FFAAC0D-A437-4283-B502-24F2A26FC7D9
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
TERM=xterm-256color
SHLVL=1
PWD=/Users/dev
OLDPWD=/Users/dev
VISUAL=vim
EDITOR=vim
PS1=$(git_prompt_info)[${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%}] 
HISTSIZE=4096
EYRC=./.eyrc
dirstacksize=5
CLICOLOR=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I get the following output when I run the mvn command as follows:

```
$mvn
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aether-api-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[1]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aether-connector-wagon-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[2]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aether-impl-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[3]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aether-spi-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[4]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
constituent[5]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
constituent[6]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
constituent[8]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar
constituent[9]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
constituent[10]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[12]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar
constituent[13]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[14]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.2.1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-artifact-3.2.1.jar
constituent[16]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-compat-3.2.1.jar
constituent[17]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-core-3.2.1.jar
constituent[18]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-embedder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[19]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-model-3.2.1.jar
constituent[20]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-model-builder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[21]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.2.1.jar
constituent[22]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.2.1.jar
constituent[23]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-settings-3.2.1.jar
constituent[24]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.2.1.jar
constituent[25]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M5.jar
constituent[26]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M5.jar
constituent[27]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[28]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
constituent[29]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.19.jar
constituent[30]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
constituent[31]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.17.jar
constituent[32]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/sisu-guice-3.1.3-no_aop.jar
constituent[33]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
constituent[34]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
constituent[35]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/wagon-file-2.6.jar
constituent[36]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/wagon-http-2.6-shaded.jar
constituent[37]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/wagon-http-shared-2.6.jar
constituent[38]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.6.jar
constituent[39]: file:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/pull/EntityReplacementMap;)V
  at org.apache.maven.settings.io.xpp3.SettingsXpp3Reader.read(SettingsXpp3Reader.java:523)
  at org.apache.maven.settings.io.xpp3.SettingsXpp3Reader.read(SettingsXpp3Reader.java:557)
  at org.apache.maven.settings.io.DefaultSettingsReader.read(DefaultSettingsReader.java:92)
  at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.readSettings(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:169)
  at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:91)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.settings(MavenCli.java:766)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:209)
  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

The JDK install is a fresh one, and also the maven installation is a fresh one. I've tried several different versions of maven, but they all give the same error. Any ideas on where I shall continue my search for the resolution of this error?

Also, the resulting command that is run (inside mvn script file, which fails) is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath /Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1 org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you run mvn with -X argument (debug)?

Comment: It seems a classpath problem. I checked the org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser class and I found it inside the plexus-utils-3.0.17.jar file. It actually has 2 constructors (one without parameter and one with the EntityReplacementMap parameter), so it seems another jar with the MXParser class is loaded before that and it contains only a void constructor. I checked old Maven releases and I found that Maven 3.0.5 had a plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar file which does not contains MXParser(EntityReplacementMap), only MXParser(). Check if other or old maven libraries are loaded in the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

The problem seemed to be caused by settings of two different versions:

This is in your PATH:

```
/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin
```

but having MAVEN_HOME set like this:

```
MAVEN_HOME=/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1
```

and M2_HOME:

```
M2_HOME=/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1
```

I wouldn't set `MAVEN_HOME` nor `M2_HOME` just simply set the PATH correctly to the Maven installation you want to use which simply means:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin
```

**Update:**

Have you unset JAVA_HOME? Where have you configured the setting of JAVA_HOME? Have you restarted you console?
I would suggest to remove JAVA_HOME settings and put a file into
`$HOME/.mavenrc` which contains the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

I would suggest to use the following (assumed you have installed Java 1.7) in your $HOME/.mavenrc (plese check the path for this on your machine):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited out those environment variables and I've also edited the question above with the new output for running "env". But the problem still remains. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort in trying to help me solve this issue. I've done as you've explained. I moved the JAVA_HOME to .maven.rc and changed it to use the specific version as you also mentioned. However the issue still persists. Do you have more suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: The file is called `.mavenrc` and **not** `.maven.rc` and should be located into your home folder.

Comment: I can't see the M2_HOME variable in the env output. Are you sure do you set it correctly? Use "export M2_HOME=/Users/dev/bin/apache-maven-3.2.1"

Answer (score 0):

The first this I would do in such a situation (after getting you variables straight, as shown by Karl-Heinz) would be to move `~/.m2/repository` to `~/.m2/repository-old` and re-run things.

(This sounds retarded, I know, but please try it and let us know the results).

Comment: This didn't work for me. It might only work for corrupted jars.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
And when I restart a Spring project ,I got this:
The error may be caused by jars in java exceptions directory which conflicts with libraries used by the external.
Try adding -Djava.ext.dirs="" argument to 'Build process VM options ' in File|Settings|Build,Execution,Deploy....

The reason is when I run "mvn install",I incorrently install a wrong jar into %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext.
The solution is to remove the wrong jars in %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext.
Or repalce ext with a normal ext folder.